# Kali Linux Grub Bootloader Windows 10

Tags: linux, kali-linux, dual-boot, grub, boot-loader

I am wanting to learn Linux, and installed Kali but I see I still have much to learn in Linux before using that distribution. I dual booted installed it alongside Windows 10 and every time I boot up I get the Grub bootloader for Kali with the option to boot into Kali or Windows. I've managed to get Windows as the default after 10 seconds of inactivity, but I want to uninstall Kali and install Ubuntu to learn Linux usage there.

What is the right way to uninstall Kali so not to loosing the ability to boot into windows? I don't think I did my installation in the recommended way in terms of the Grub.

Comment: Actually I just found this 
https://www.techmesto.com/uninstall-linux-grub-dual-boot-windows8/
I'm gonna try it a little later

Comment: You can delete grub bootloader by mounting your EFI partition. To delete kali just format its partition.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove Kali as specified in the link in your comment. Do a fresh install of Ubuntu alongside Win10, then when partitioning make sure you keep the Windows partitions intact and install Ubuntu over the partitions used by Kali. (You might want to repartition these Kali partitions first.)